# Dispatching database update jobs within a transaction - Rollback query

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, queue, jobs

I have a question regarding dispatching jobs for updating a database within a transaction. If any of these jobs encounter an error, will the database automatically rollback to its previous state?

Here is my code:

```php
DB::transaction(
    function () use ($allowance, $currentAllowanceHistory, $newStartAt, $currentStartAt, $updateData) {
        $allowance->update($updateData);

        $currentAllowanceHistory->update(['started_at' => $newStartAt]);

        [$startDate, $endDate] = $this->calculateDateRange($currentStartAt, $newStartAt);

        $jobs = $this->createLoadUpdateWorkingHistoryJobBatches($startDate, $endDate);

        return Bus::batch($jobs)
            ->then(function () {
                Log::info('Update working history batch successfully');
            })
            ->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
                Log::error($e->getMessage(), $batch->failedJobIds);
            })->dispatch();
    }
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can change your code like this

```
try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $allowance->update($updateData);
    
        $currentAllowanceHistory->update(['started_at' => $newStartAt]);
    
        [$startDate, $endDate] = $this->calculateDateRange($currentStartAt, $newStartAt);
    
        $jobs = $this->createLoadUpdateWorkingHistoryJobBatches($startDate, $endDate);
    
        Bus::batch($jobs)
        ->then(function () {
            Log::info('Update working history batch successfully');

            DB::commit();
        })
        ->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage(), $batch->failedJobIds);

            DB::rollback();
        })->dispatch();
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        DB::rollback();
    }
```

instead of

```
DB::transaction(
function () use ($allowance, $currentAllowanceHistory, $newStartAt, $currentStartAt, $updateData) {
    $allowance->update($updateData);

    $currentAllowanceHistory->update(['started_at' => $newStartAt]);

    [$startDate, $endDate] = $this->calculateDateRange($currentStartAt, $newStartAt);

    $jobs = $this->createLoadUpdateWorkingHistoryJobBatches($startDate, $endDate);

    return Bus::batch($jobs)
        ->then(function () {
            Log::info('Update working history batch successfully');
        })
        ->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage(), $batch->failedJobIds);
        })->dispatch();
});
```